# Siddur & chumash -- which gets stacked on top?

Tags: jewish-books, prayer-book, pentateuch-chumash, kavod

I've seen this one asked over and over again, and always heard different things.

Do you stack a chumash on top of a siddur, or the other way around?

Comment: I've always heard Chumash on top of everything else, then Na"Ch, then other Siddurim-type of Sifrei Kodesh. But I do not have a source handy for this. I know there is one, though.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4683/stacking-seforim

Answer (score 7):

Aruch Hashulchan ([YD 283:6](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%92#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A8.D7.A4.D7.92_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.95)) equates all printed sefarim in kedusha and in terms of placing one on top of another:

יורה דעה סימן רפג סעיף ו

וכתב רבינו הרמ"א דכל זה בחומשים העשויים בגליון כספר תורה. אבל בשלנו שהם נכרכים – אין חילוק בין חומש לנביא. עד כאן לשונו.
כלומר: דוודאי כל ספרי קודש הם קדושים, אך זהו קדושה כללית. אבל בפרטי הקדושות זה למעלה מזה, וספר תורה למעלה מכולם – זהו כשנכתבו לשם קדושת ספר תורה על הקלף כדין. ***אבל סתם ספרים כשלנו, וכל שכן בספרים הנדפסים – אין בהם פרטי קדושות אלא כולם קדושתם שוה. וגם לעניין הנחה זה על זה – אין בהם מעלה זה על זה***, וכמו שכתבתי בסוף סימן הקודם. ואין חילוק בין תורה שבכתב לתורה שבעל פה, דכולם קדושים, ומניחים זה על זה (כן נראה לי).

Answer (score 6):

It's generally accepted to stack sfarim (books) in order of holiness, with the holiest on top. 
As a chumash is considered to be holier than a Siddur the Chumash goes on top.

See [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4683/stacking-seforim) for a quote from the Shulchan Aruch.

Modern day Siddurim are a little more complicated, as they contain (often at the back) weekday and other Torah readings, but the generally accepted practice is to place them below Chumashim.

Comment: Any source to support your claim of what's "generally accepted practice"? Not that I doubt it.

Comment: Mesorah. It's the practice in my family and I've noticed that it seems to be how other frum Jews act too. Of course you can look at the above quote from the Shulchan Aruch, but mesorah is a great source too.