# Does a Talmudic dictionary have kedusha?

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, kedusha-holiness

May one place a Talmudic dictionary like the Otzar Rashei Teivos on top of other holy sefarim? I had always assumed that it has the status of a sefer, but others have expressed doubts on this issue.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&pgnum=141

Comment: @DoubleAA, that's relevant to degrading them, not to putting them above holy books.

Comment: 1) I'm not sure why that's different. 2) Even if that is different, it is worth linking to anyway as similar/related.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4683 and also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25651 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15064

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the Aruch Hashulchan writes that **no** printed works have kedushas seforim.

Comment: The standard Jastrow prints שם הוי”ה

Answer (score 1):

In principle, undoubtedly. Case in point - [ספר הערוך](http://hebrewbooks.org/42538) who's definitions [provide insight](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A#cite_note-1) into the understanding of the Talmud.

On the type of dictionary that you are asking about, where it is more collecting words without interpretation, it may be different, however I looked up the specific one you referenced, and the [online image](http://www.nehora.com/products.php?product=Thesaurus-of-Hebrew-Abbreviations-%28Hebrew%29-Otzar-Rashei-Tevot-----%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8-%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA%252d%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%96%D7%99-%D7%95%D7%93%D7%91-%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9F) I found shows a Roshei Tevos which is a complete verse from Tehilim, so entire verses of Torah are printed there, intended to enable learning. So it would be strange to call it an exception - certainly לחומרא.

Comment: Are you arguing that the Aruch is a regular dictionary or a special kind of dictionary? If the latter, how do you prove to regular dictionaries? If the former, how do you know the Aruch has the status of a Sefer?

Comment: @DoubleAA, if I replace "regular dictionary" with "Talmudic dictionary" in your comment, I can't make heads or tails of your question.

Comment: That's because Talmudic dictionary is not a status. If you think the Aruch is a unique dictionary because he gives pshatim in the Gemara like any Rishon, then how can you learn from their to the Otzar? If you think the Aruch is just a dictionary about Talmudic terms, how do you know it's a Sefer?

Comment: @DoubleAA A dictionary that defines words in the Talmud? It may not be a status, but it is certainly a category.