# Looking for a good tikkun kor'im

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, torah-reading, pentateuch-chumash

I have an old [*Tikkun Kor'im* by Mishor](http://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D---%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8---%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C) whose cover has [literally come off](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51129/does-a-detached-binding-of-a-sefer-get-stacked-in-the-same-position) (ah, the motivation for that question is revealed!).

Now that i'm in the market for a new *tikkun*, i'd like to make sure i get a good one. There are a few things that i feel are lacking in the old one, that i'd like to make sure are there in a new one:

- Differentiating between *shva na*s and *shva nach*s
- Showing when a *kamatz* is a *kamatz katan*
- Providing the weekday aliyah breaks

Comment: Unfortunately i did not think to ask before actually buying a new one, but hopefully the question and answer(s) will help other people choose a good tikkun.

Comment: Feldheim tenach simanim does have all 3. shwa na and shwa nach.  kamatz gadol and kamatz katan. It also has dagesh chazak and dagesh kal(though maybe that's not that important particualrly given that shwa are marked), so you're right to want kamatz and shwa covered, which it does. It doesn't have chirik gadol marked.. though neither does the one in that pic on the accepted answer either

Comment: @barlop The one in the answer is that.

Comment: I'm saying it doesn't have chirik gadol, are you trying to tell me that the one in the answer has a chirik gadol? Look here is a pic of part of the pic in the answer http://i.imgur.com/YzgjAXr.png  Exodus 1:2 (Exodus chapter 1 verse 2) in the pic there. Now see where it says Shimon and Layvee I put a square around it. Can you see that Layvee would be a chirik gadol, but it's not marked any different from Shimon which is a chirik katan. So no, the answer doesn't have chirik gadol, (the chirik gadol is what I speak of). Though it does have the 3 you mention.

Comment: @barlop I was on my phone earlier. I mean, the one in the answer is the Feldheim Simanim.

Comment: The one in the answer is the Feldheim Tikkun Simanim, I wrote of the Feldheim Tenach Simanim. I suppose they have the same markings though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I decided to get the Simanim tikkun. It's really cool. It provides all of the requirements in the question, and more.

[image: Example page of pocket-sized version from KodeshBook.co.il]

This is an example of the beginning of parshat Shmot in the [pocket-sized edition](http://www.kodeshbook.co.il/product.asp?productid=5176). Some features to notice:

- *Shva na/ch* -- ונפתלי, for example, shows both versions
- *Kamatz katan* -- on וימת
- Weekday aliyah breaks -- the diamonds before ויקם and ויעבדו

They also help the reader avoid making common mistakes in other places:

- The large letter in הבה is to call attention to the fact that the note is early in the word
- Lines over letters that have no dagesh when you might expect them to have
- A grayed out silent ש in יששכר in the Torah side
- Highlighted sections in the Torah side, with notes (at the bottom) comparing it to other parts of the Torah that you might get confused with -- generally where the words are similar but slightly different, or have a different trop
- היה במצרים is printed smaller to show that it is one segment, and should not be broken up as ויוסף היה, במצרים.

Some other nice features not shown in this image include:

- Not printing a *psik* and a *munach legarmeih* in the same manner
- Showing Yom Tov aliyot as well

---

I am not being paid to advertise this. I'm just happy with my new *tikkun*. :)

Comment: One pretty major thing it doesn't have is Breuer's text of Tanakh, so it'll have errors. A solid layout though. Thus more useful for review but not for first learning the text.

Comment: I would have suggested the same thing. My experience is with the K'tav (horrible American tikkun), Yosher, and Simanim editions. One beef with the Simanim is that it doesn't note all of the unique letters in Torah, for example, the ו שבור in ברית שלום in the beginning of Pinchas.

Comment: You might want to note also if it includes the Haftarot and/or Megillot with "both sides" for practice. (It does IINM.)

Comment: This looks interesting. The image, however, doesn't really depict the features that you mentioned. Can you edit your answer to provide a link to info about this Tikun directly? The link seems to go to the store's web site, and I'm having trouble locating this specific sefer's specs. Also, if you know of a U.S. distributor, please provide that info as well.

Answer (score 4):

I now use the *[Chorev Tikkun](http://www.chorev.co.il/Product/40159/%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D---%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%91-)* and with the *Simanim Tikkun* on the side.

Benefits of the *Chorev*:

- Uses the actual Breuer text.
- Distinguishes *shva nah*/*nach* and *kamatz katan*.
- The side of the page without trop looks exactly like the sefer torah - the *Simanim* has random highlights and other markings on the
  "torah" side which I find distracting.
- Both sides of the page have a really nice clear typesetting.
- The Haftarot have the proper paragraph breaks of the Klaf - Simanim removes them all.

But I still keep the *Simanim* open on the side because it has:

- The footnotes that show you where potential pitfalls are.
- Minchat Shai (there is now a version of the Chorev that has that too)

Comment: What is the "Breuer text" ?

Comment: The textual version of Tanach by Dr Mordechai Breuer - very close to the Aleppo Codex -considered the most authoritative version of Tanach but we don't have it for most of the 5 books of Torah

Answer (score 3):

I have both the *Tikkun Simanim* described, and also the ArtScroll Tikkun (Kestenbaum edition, author Rabbi Avie Gold) that I got as a gift.  I assume that the Bar Mitzvah presentation gift edition that ArtScroll offers would have similar language and printing to the ArtScroll I have.

I inherited an old Tikkun from a relative who was a ba'al korey of distinction, but it now serves only as a keepsake.  In comparison, these new ones are great.  Personally I find both the ArtScroll and the Simanim useful, depending on what I need for fine-tuning a particular parsha or whether I'm helping somebody else prepare a new reading.

Differences between them that I think especially worth noting:  ArtScroll has English translations of Torah and Haftarah and much supplementary material in English.  Simanim does not.  The print in the ArtScroll gift edition is a bit larger than the printing in my Tikkun Simanim.  But, although the ArtScroll distinguishes between kamatz katan and gadol, and sheva nach and sheva na, both in the Torah and Haftarah texts, it doesn't have the other helpful features Scimonster lists in the answer above.

21 December:  I'm adding this paragraph because a relative said I should comment on one feature of Simanim, about which Scimonster's post says, 
"Highlighted sections in the Torah side, with notes (at the bottom) comparing it to other parts of the Torah that you might get confused with – generally where the words are similar but slightly different, or have a different trop." There's an example on the sample page he included.
I don't find this intrusive, but you should be aware of it if you expect the Torah side of your Tikkun to be absolutely identical to what you see in a Torah scroll.

The *Tikkum Simanim* is virtually all in Hebrew and all its wonderful features are explained only in Hebrew.  So if you get it for someone whose Hebrew is weak, translate for them if you can, or at least give them a copy of Scimonster's description.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Chaim! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend the Tikkun Korim Yosher. Is all in Hebrew , the whole Torah, Haftarot and Five Megilot,  parallel with vowels and without vowels and at the end of the book the laws for reading the Torah both in Hebrew and English. You can find it here

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00H54VW38?ref=myi_title_dp](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00H54VW38)

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Maximiliano and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 0):

I was reading through this old thread and wanted to raise an additional option along with some questions.

Tikkun Korim *Ish Matzliach* by HaRav Mazuz has become quite popular. It seems to be a worthy competitor to the Chorev Tikkun. I am referring to the editing that has both Ashkenazi and Sefardi traditions.

https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/tikkun-korim-ish-matzliach/63854

- Does this tikkun fulfill all the requirements that the initial questioner mentioned?
- Is the ktav written in ktav Ashkenazi or Sefardi?
- How does the accuracy compare to the Chorev edition?
- Does the grammar introduction provide information that other tikunim do not?

Comment: It's in sefardi script and has some changes to the traditional Torah text that R Mazuz decided on his own based on grammar rules to emend the Torah text. Arguably heretical.

Comment: Do you have examples?

Comment: Consider http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=53812