# Does a (printed) Tanach have more Kedusha than a (printed) Torah?

Tags: jewish-books, pentateuch-chumash, kedusha-holiness

Does the amount of Kedusha that a sefer has add up, or is it capped?

Is Tanach equal to Torah plus Nach, or is it limited to just Torah?

My intention when I first posted this was for which one should be put higher on a stack (if we assume that there are different levels of Kedusha for printed books), but now I see that there may be other Nafkot Mina!

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: A handwritten Tanakh has less holiness than a handwritten Torah scroll since by attaching other stuff to it you have invalidated it as a Torah scroll, but I have no idea how to determine a printed object's 'holiness level'.

Comment: I believe as far as halacha lema'aseh (I would need to check the source - hence the comment) that if a person does not lein the haftarah from a klaf that he should lein specifically out of tanach as opposed to the back of chumash.

Comment: @Dov That's a common misconception. The preference is to read out of a complete book, so if the haftara is from Joshua you can use any complete Book of Joshua. It so happens most places that rely on that position just buy a single Tanakh for convenience since it's cheap enough and readily available, but there's no advantage to a Tanakh over a Joshua for the purpose of reading a haftara from Joshua. Whether the books of Torah or Ketuvim are included is completely irrelevant to the whole discussion. (Related [link](/a/84007/))

Comment: [This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15863/3483) says that the Aruch Hashulchan, referencing the Rema, holds that all sefarim (Chumash and Navi mentioned specifically, but then he broadens it to include even Oral Torah, so it presumably also includes Ketuvim and other books with the Name written) are considered equal for the purpose of stacking.

Comment: @DoubleAA **thank you** for clearing that up. I've seen places insist on using a Tanach for *Shir HaShirim*, for example, when by definition any book you use will have the complete Sefer. (How do we come out with Trei Asar? Is any Yonah or Ovadiah good enough on its own?)

Comment: @Shalom There's a yerushalmi that sounds like yonah on its own is not good enough but the "regular" sources are largely silent on the matter in a way that implies it would be ok. A low risk / low gain sort of chumra I guess.